# I can use assert from nodejs instead of if condition in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can use [`Assert` function](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) **from nodejs** instead of if condition in nodejs: `import assert from 'node:assert';` it's meant to testing only or I can use in my functions which are not tests?

For example I don't use `if`, only `assert`:

```
async function getUser() {
 const user = getDb().selectUsers().first();

  assert(user, new Error('USER_NOT_FOUND'));
  // in if I'll do: if (!user) throw new Error('USER_NOT_FOUND');
   
  console.log({ foundUser: user });
  ...

}
```

This is something okay to do? or it's bad pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Assert is meant to be used for testing and not performing logic.